# How to access DB values outside of try-catch block in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3, in that I have `try-catch` block. In that `try` block I performed insert operation using eloquent query. Now I want to access the `id` of transaction, outside of the `try-catch` block the code as follow,

```
function sample(){   
 try
    {
        $User->name=$username;
    }
     catch(){}
return redirect::route('edit',$User->id);
}
```

Where `id` is set as auto increment, when I call `$User->id` it returns an empty value. How do I access it?

Comment: what error will be shown? and `id` column contain in` user `table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save your data first as

```
function sample(){   
   try
   {
       $User->name=$username;
   }
   catch(){}
   if($User->save()) {
       return redirect::route('edit',$User->id);
   }
}
```

After save, $User->id should be the last id inserted.

Comment: i tried but it will produce $User->id not defined error.

Comment: Eloquent assumes that the primary key is "id" only. Did u changed the id column in your users table

Comment: ya that's correct.i am not changed.thats work.thanks bro